# Retry topic is not creating in spring-kafka non blocking retry( 3.0 version)

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-boot-3

// As we can't pass @BackOff "delay" value dynamically by using @Value placeholder from config file. So I am trying to build by using RetryTopicConfiguration instead of @RetryableTopic annotation .I tried with @RetryableTopic anotation before and it was working absolutely fine same thing I want to achieve by using RetryTopicConfiguration but it was not creating retry topic .I want to create only three topic for same retry interval  main, main-dlt ,and main-retry but its not creating main-retry topic

```
//Before using like it
@RetryableTopic(kafkaTemplate = "kafkaCustomTemplate",
attempts = "${max-retry-attempt-ms}",
listenerContainerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000, multiplier = 1, maxDelay = 100000),
autoCreateTopics = "false",
sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy = SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
```

```
//Now wanted to use like this
    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration bankNotificationRetryAbleTopicConfig() {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .fixedBackOff(retryInterval)
                .maxAttempts(maxRetryAttempts)
                .sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy(SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
                .retryTopicSuffix("-retry")
                .dltSuffix(RetryTopicConstants.DEFAULT_DLT_SUFFIX)
                .dltHandlerMethod("KafkaDTNotificationConsumer", "processDLTMessage")
                .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory())
                .create(kafkaTemplate());
    }
```

```
>! package za.co.hellogroup.hellobank.banknotifications.config;
@EnableKafka
@Configuration("KafkaQueueConfiguration")
public class KafkaQueueConfiguration {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaQueueConfiguration.class);


    @Autowired
    private NotificationAlert notificationAlert;

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMappingRepository errorMapping;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, consumerBootstrap);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, BankNotificationsConstants.IS_ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetType);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, fixedInterval);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollInterval);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfig);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, jsonTypeMapping);
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, BankNotificationsConstants.TRUSTED_PACKAGES_ALL);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, deJsonDelegate);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, heartbeatInterval);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, SslConfigs.DEFAULT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean(value = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean(value = "kafkaCustomTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, consumerBootstrap);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, jsonTypeMapping);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfig);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }


    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration bankNotificationRetryAbleTopicConfig() {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .fixedBackOff(retryInterval)
                .maxAttempts(maxRetryAttempts)
                .sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy(SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
                .retryTopicSuffix("-retry")
                .dltSuffix(RetryTopicConstants.DEFAULT_DLT_SUFFIX)
                .dltHandlerMethod("KafkaDTNotificationConsumer", "processDLTMessage")
                .listenerFactory(kafkaListenerContainerFactory())
                .create(kafkaTemplate());
    }
}
package za.co.hellogroup.hellobank.banknotifications.event;

@Service("KafkaDTNotificationConsumer")
@Transactional
public class KafkaDTNotificationConsumer {


    @Value(("${max-retry-attempt-ms}"))
    private String maxRetryAttempts;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaDTNotificationConsumer.class.getClass());

    //   I was using @Retryalbetopic befow like below 
//    @RetryableTopic(kafkaTemplate = "kafkaCustomTemplate",
//            attempts = "${max-retry-attempt-ms}",
//            listenerContainerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
//            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000, multiplier = 1, maxDelay = 100000),
//            autoCreateTopics = "false",
//            sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy = SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.DT.ATM}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "${group.id}")
    @KafkaListener(topics = "test-a", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId = "test-grp")
    public void onMessage(@Payload EftTransactionDetail eftTransactionDetail
            , @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String receivedTopic
            , @Header(name = RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS, required = false) Integer retryAttempts
            , Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        EftTransactionDetail cloneEftTransactionDetail = new EftTransactionDetail(eftTransactionDetail);
        log.info("Consume started EftTransactionDetail :: {}", eftTransactionDetail);
        log.info("Received message from :: {} topic and retryAttempt :: {} ", receivedTopic, retryAttempts == null ? 0 : retryAttempts);
        sendTransactionNotification(cloneEftTransactionDetail, acknowledgment);
    }


    public void processDLTMessage(EftTransactionDetail eftTransactionDetail
            , @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE) String lastRetryException
            , @Header(RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS) Integer attempt
            , Acknowledgment ack) {
        log.info("--------------------------------------DLT Handler----------------------------------------------------");
        log.info("Retrying record :: {} and retry attempt :: {}", eftTransactionDetail, attempt);
        log.info("Last retrying exception :: {}", lastRetryException);
        String lastExceptionCode = lastRetryException.contains(BankNotificationsConstants.SEMI_COLON)
                ? lastRetryException.split(BankNotificationsConstants.SEMI_COLON)[1].trim() : BankNotificationsConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        log.info("Last exception message code :: {}", lastExceptionCode);
        ErrorMappingDAO errorMappingDAO = errorMapping.findByUniqueTagAndPartnerErrorCode(SystemTag.HB, lastExceptionCode).orElse(null);
        log.info("ErrorMappingDAO :: {} ", errorMappingDAO);
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().setIfAbsent(BankNotificationsConstants.SMS_REDIS_PREFIX + eftTransactionDetail.getAtdEntryId(), eftTransactionDetail.getAtdEntryId());
        String alertMessage = BankNotificationsConstants.RETRY_ATTEMPT_EXCEEDED;
        if (errorMappingDAO != null)
            alertMessage = errorMappingDAO.getResponseErrorDescription() + BankNotificationsConstants.DOUBLE_COLON + BankNotificationsConstants.RETRY_ATTEMPT_EXCEEDED;

        notificationAlert.sendAlertNotificationEmail(alertMessage, eftTransactionDetail.getAtdEntryId()
                , eftTransactionDetail.getAccountNumber(), eftTransactionDetail.getTrlCode());
        ack.acknowledge();
        log.info("Record :: {} has been acknowledged in recovery callback", eftTransactionDetail);

    }

}
```